# Meteor: How can I retrieve the inserted _id inside a method?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, methods

I have a meteor method to insert a document. The id for that document serves as a url extension. After the document is created, I also send an email via the same method. In the email, I want to include a link to the url extension. How can I do that?

```
//create a video
Meteor.methods({
  createVideo: function(doc) {
    Videos.insert({title: doc.title, userId: this.userId, date: new Date()});

    var emailData = {
        message: "Click the link below to go to your video.",
        buttontext: "View My Video",
        buttonlink: "http://sample.com/vids/" + ???????
    },

    body = EmailGenerator.generateHtml("actionEmailTemplate", emailData);

    Meteor.call("sendMailgunEmail",
                "account@sample.com",
                "sample",
                [Meteor.user().emails[0].address],
                "Your video is live!",
                body
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert) for `collection.insert`:

> Insert a document in the collection. Returns its unique _id.

Just assign the return value of the insert to a variable you can reference later:

```
//create a video
Meteor.methods({
  createVideo: function(doc) {
    var videoId = Videos.insert({title: doc.title, userId: this.userId, date: new Date()});

    var emailData = {
        message: "Click the link below to go to your video.",
        buttontext: "View My Video",
        buttonlink: "http://sample.com/vids/" + videoId
    },

    body = EmailGenerator.generateHtml("actionEmailTemplate", emailData);

    Meteor.call("sendMailgunEmail",
                "account@sample.com",
                "sample",
                [Meteor.user().emails[0].address],
                "Your video is live!",
                body
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

From Meteor Docs:

**collection.insert(doc, [callback])**

> Insert a document in the collection. Returns its unique _id.

So you can grab the `_id` from your insert by storing it in a local variable

```
var videoId = Videos.insert({title: doc.title, userId: this.userId, date: new Date()});
```